# DocuSign API - GET Status of Single Envelope Returns Results for Multiple Envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

I'm polling the DocuSign API to get the status of individual Envelopes and have been able to successfully make the requests. I've just noticed that when I check more than one Envelope in a row it returns the status for the first Envelope I checked as well as the current Envelope I'm checking.

I'm making a series of GET requests for 2-3 Envelopes like this in a loop:

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?envelope_ids=7cf7c669-dd2e-4838-aa0b-53fefce4f8a6
```

which returns the status for this individual envelope. I then make a 2nd request for a different Envelope ID, e.g.:

```
 GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes?envelope_ids=21cf8b7d-86c6-4613-a362-05e073dc0e6f
```

and I get an array of the 2 Envelope Statuses, even though I only requested the status of a single Envelope. I know I can use a Comma separated list of envelopeId values but I'm just specifying a single envelopeId with each request here.

I would have expected to receive a single Envelope Status when I'm requesting a single envelopeId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to receive a single/specific envelopes, you should use a different endpoint:

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}
```

See more information here:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get

Or if you just want to retreive status information use this:

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status
```